# $||*||_p$ p-Norm for Vector That is Not in $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

My instructor gave us a problem asking to solve the 2-Norm of **p** also written as$||p||_2$

However, **p** is in an inner product space $V=C[0,1]$ which means it is a function.

(Specifically, **p** $=\frac{3}{2}x$)

I'm not sure how to compute the 2-Norm for a function because I thought it was only applicable to vectors in $R^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\in C([0,1])$ then
$$ ||f||_2=\Big(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\;dx\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
In fact, for each real number $1\leq p<\infty$ there is a corresponding $p$-norm, defined by
$$|f||_p=\Big(\int_0^1|f(x)|^p\;dx\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Comment: So if p-Norm is defined on C[0,1], would my calculation of the 2-norm of $p$ simply be the same value of $p$?

Comment: No, the $p$ in my answer (which is the commonly used letter for whatever reason) is not the same as the function $p(x)=\frac{3}{2}x$ in your question. Instead, $||p||_2=\sqrt{\int_0^1\frac{9}{4}x^2\;dx}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: note to self: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lp-Space.html